# How to printf long long

Tags: c, long-integer, pi

I'm doing a program that aproximate PI and i'm trying to use long long, but it isn't working.
Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
typedef long long num;
main(){
    num pi;
    pi=0;
    num e, n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(e=0; 1;e++){
      pi += ((pow((-1.0),e))/(2.0*e+1.0));
      if(e%n==0)
        printf("%15lld -> %1.16lld\n",e, 4*pi);
      //printf("%lld\n",4*pi);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing your problem is more with the `scanf` than the `printf`.

Comment: `pow((-1.0),e)` would be much better expressed as `e % 2 ? 1 : -1`

Answer (score 77):

`%lld` is the standard C99 way, but that doesn't work on the compiler that I'm using (mingw32-gcc v4.6.0). The way to do it on this compiler is: `%I64d`

So try this:

```
if(e%n==0)printf("%15I64d -> %1.16I64d\n",e, 4*pi);
```

and

```
scanf("%I64d", &n);
```

The only way I know of for doing this in a completely portable way is to use the defines in `<inttypes.h>`.

In your case, it would look like this:

```
scanf("%"SCNd64"", &n);
//...    
if(e%n==0)printf("%15"PRId64" -> %1.16"PRId64"\n",e, 4*pi);
```

It really is very ugly... but at least it is portable.

Comment: It's not your compiler but your C library that's responsible here.  You're using the Microsoft C library, which doesn't support `%lld`, which is a C99 feature (although so is `inttypes.h`).

Comment: To be more specific, it's msvcrt.dll, which is the ancient (circa 1998) version of the C standard library that was originally written for VC++ 6.0, and ships with Windows for backwards compatibility purposes. MinGW uses that ancient version, because that's the only one that comes out of the box with Windows. But modern VC++ runtime handle `%lld` properly.

Comment: Visual C++ 2013 seems to support the %lld format element

Comment: @PavelMinaev msvcrt.dll that comes with windows isn't ancient.

Comment: It has been patched, sure, but I haven't heard of any updates to its actual features since VC++ 6.0 days.

Comment: One of the benefits of using new WSL is you can be in the modern days of writing C with updated GCC or CLANG. Much more compatible than MINGW.

Answer (score 3):

- Your `scanf()` statement needs to use `%lld` too.
- Your loop does not have a terminating condition.
- There are far too many parentheses and far too few spaces in the expression

  ```
  pi += pow(-1.0, e) / (2.0*e + 1.0);
  ```
- You add one on the first iteration of the loop, and thereafter zero to the value of 'pi'; this does not change the value much.
- You should use an explicit return type of `int` for `main()`.
- On the whole, it is best to specify `int main(void)` when it ignores its arguments, though that is less of a categorical statement than the rest.
- I dislike the explicit licence granted in C99 to omit the return from the end of `main()` and don't use it myself; I write `return 0;` to be explicit.

I think the whole algorithm is dubious when written using `long long`; the data type probably should be more like `long double` (with `%Lf` for the `scanf()` format, and maybe `%19.16Lf` for the `printf()` formats.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, %d is for a `int`

So `%1.16lld` makes no sense, because %d is an integer

That typedef you do, is also unnecessary, use the type straight ahead, makes a much more readable code.

What you want to use is the type `double`, for calculating pi
and then using `%f` or `%1.16f`.

Comment: It's not really "illegal"... it's MSVC-specific, I think.

Comment: Incorrect.  Read the [spec for printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html).  `%lld` is exactly how you print a `long long`.  (Of course, the `1.16` may not do what you want...  But it is perfectly valid.  It means use a minimum field width of 1 and to print 16 digits.)

Comment: @Mehrdad You mean `%lld`? It's specified in C99 7.19.6.1.

Comment: @Pascal: Oh I had no idea, even better then.
@hexa: Sorry I was referring to `lld`, not decimal points... I thought that's what you meant, my bad.

Comment: [MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) uses a format such as `%I64d` or `%lld` for the 64-bit `long long` formats.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // acos(0.0) will return value of pi/2, inverse of cos(0) is pi/2 
    double pi = 2 * acos(0.0);
    int n; // upto 6 digit
    scanf("%d",&n); //precision with which you want the value of pi
    printf("%.*lf\n",n,pi); // * will get replaced by n which is the required precision
```

Comment: Sure, I will add some more details @double-beep