# sscanf returning wrong numbers for long long int variables

Tags: c

I am having trouble parsing the input file in the [Auction Problem](http://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problems.php?pid=268598303201105&round=146094915502528) of [Facebook HackerCup](http://www.facebook.com/hackercup).

Every line of the input file contains 9 space-separated integers: N, P1, W1, M, K, A, B, C and D. According to the input constraints the numbers can be as big as 10^18. So, I decided to use `long long int` to store the variables.

I am doing:

```
FILE *fr;
long long int N, P1, W1, M, K, A, B, C, D;
char line[1024];    
fr = fopen ("input.txt", "rt");

while(fgets(line, 1024, fr) != NULL)
{
    sscanf(line, "%lld %lld %lld %lld %lld %lld %lld %lld %lld", &N, &P1, &W1, &M, &K, &A, &B, &C, &D);
    printf("N:%lld P1:%lld W1:%lld M:%lld K:%lld A:%lld B:%lld C:%lld D:%lld\n\n", N, P1, W1, M, K, A, B, C, D);
}
```

For a line `81834165 9999991 1 9999991 9999989 389999650 169999844 799999121 149999837`, I get `N:81834165 P1:4367 W1:9999991 M:4078336 K:1 A:2292512 B:9999991 C:2292488 D:9999989`

Can you please help me to point out the problem in this code? Any recommendation about parsing a similar file would also be appreciated.

---

Edit: I should add that it works for `int` variables as in:

```
char line[1024];    
int N, P1, W1, M, K, A, B, C, D;

strcpy(line, "81834165 9999991 1 9999991 9999989 389999650 169999844 799999121 149999837");
printf("Line: %s", line);
sscanf(line, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &N, &P1, &W1, &M, &K, &A, &B, &C, &D);
printf("ret_val:%d\n\n", ret_val);
printf("N:%d P1:%d W1:%d M:%d K:%d A:%d B:%d C:%d D:%d\n\n", N, P1, W1, M, K, A, B, C, D);
```

---

I just noticed something strange. Printing more than one `long long int` variables in one `printf()` outputs wrong values while printing them in separate `printf()`s outputs right values. I mean:

```
printf("N:%lld P1:%lld\n", N, P1);
printf("N:%lld\n", N);
printf("P1:%lld\n", P1);
```

outputs:

```
N:81834165 P1:2009288239
N:81834165
P1:9999991
```

Do you have any idea about it?

---

**SOLUTION**

I have found out that the problem was with the compiler I was using (gcc on MinGW)
On this compiler, I needed to replace `%lld` with `%I64d`. I found a similar problem at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400180/how-to-printf-long-long).

---

Comment: It's work fine for me. please send your whole code. (I just wrap it with `#include <stdio.h>` , `int main(){ ` and `return 0;}` I also guess that the problem is in the reading from file, so your test with `int` doesn't prove anything.

Comment: yes, it is exactly as yours. But it doesn't work for me. Note that it works for `int` variables.

Comment: Well, since the same code works for me, but not for you, I suggest you to run it in debugger. Also, what happens if you use `strcpy` (like your second code) with `long long int` (as your first code)?

Comment: The `'t'` in the mode argument is not portable.

Comment: @asaelr it's the same result with `strcpy`. I will check it with a debugger.

Comment: @pmg; the problem is not `'t'`, it works for `int` variables. And, it doesn't work even with `strcpy` for `long long int` variables

Comment: Are you compiling with a C99 implementation? `long long` did not exist (except as an extension) in C89. Increase the level of warning of your compiler and mind the warnings. You can check for a C99 implementation with `printf("%ld", __STDC_VERSION__);` If it doesn't exist or is less than 199901 you don't have a C99 implementation.

Comment: Hi @pmg, I get ` error: '\_\_STDC_VERSION\_\_' undeclared here (not in a function)`

Comment: can you please see the last edit I made in the question? printing multiple `long long int` in one `printf()` statement outputs wrong values

Comment: Maybe the error is in the printf. Try printfing a long long that is larger than 4294967296.

Comment: @MrLister; yes, it can't print a number bigger than `2^32=4294967296`. It can not print 2 `long long int`s smaller than that as well. Is it a problem about my compiler(gcc from MinGW)? Or, a general bug?

Comment: Rather than use `sscanf(line, "%lld %lld %lld ...`, use `#define S64 "%I64d"  sscanf(line, S64 S64 S64 ..` then code only needs to conditionally compile using `#define S64 "%I64d"` or `#define S64 "%lld"`.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, `%lld` doesn't work correctly. According to [this page](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/118149-long-long-int-gplusplus-mingw.html), "You should use `%I64d` instead of `%lld` as MinGW uses MSVCRT."

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check the return value of `sscanf()`. There might be subtle errors in your input that causes it to abort after the first few conversions.