# print fibo big numbers in c++ or c language

Tags: c++, c, recursion, fibonacci

I write this code for show  fibonacci series using recursion.But It not show correctly for n>43 (ex: for n=100 show:-980107325).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void fibonacciSeries(int);

void fibonacciSeries(int n)
{
static long d = 0, e = 1;
long c;
if (n>1)
{
    c = d + e;
    d = e;
    e = c;
    printf("%d \n", c);
    fibonacciSeries(n - 1);
}
}

int main()
{
long a, n;
long long i = 0, j = 1, f;
printf("How many number you want to print in the fibonnaci series :\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

printf("\nFibonacci Series: ");
printf("%d", 0);
fibonacciSeries(n);
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define what do you mean by "not show correctly".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to printf long long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400180/how-to-printf-long-long)

Comment: fib(100) is `354,224,848,179,261,915,075` - this is too big even for an unsigned 64 bit integer.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I want to show until 100 but for 100 show : -980107325

Comment: Why are you unsure whether this is C or C++? FYI, it certainly looks like plain C to me. (And teach yourself to steer away from `conio.h` functions.)

Answer (score 5):

The value of `fib(100)` is so large that it will overflow even a 64 bit number. To operate on such large values, you need to do [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). Arbitrary-precision arithmetic is not provided by C nor C++ standard libraries, so you'll need to either implement it yourself or use a library written by someone else.

For smaller values that do fit your `long long`, your problem is that you use the wrong `printf` format specifier. To print a `long long`, you need to use `%lld`.

Answer (score 4):

Code overflows the range of the integer used `long`.
Could use `long long`, but even that may not handle [Fib(100)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) which needs at least 69 bits.

Code could use `long double` if `1.0/LDBL_EPSILON > 3.6e20`

Various libraries exist to handle very large integers.

For this task, all that is needed is a way to add two large integers.  Consider using a string.  An inefficient but simply string addition follows.  No contingencies for buffer overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

char *str_revese_inplace(char *s) {
  char *left = s;
  char *right = s + strlen(s);
  while (right > left) {
    right--;
    char t = *right;
    *right = *left;
    *left = t;
    left++;
  }
  return s;
}

char *str_add(char *ssum, const char *sa, const char *sb) {
  const char *pa = sa + strlen(sa);
  const char *pb = sb + strlen(sb);
  char *psum = ssum;
  int carry = 0;
  while (pa > sa || pb > sb || carry) {
    int sum = carry;
    if (pa > sa) sum += *(--pa) - '0';
    if (pb > sb) sum += *(--pb) - '0';
    *psum++ = sum % 10 + '0';
    carry = sum / 10;
  }
  *psum = '\0';
  return str_revese_inplace(ssum);
}

int main(void) {
  char fib[3][300];
  strcpy(fib[0], "0");
  strcpy(fib[1], "1");
  int i;
  for (i = 2; i <= 1000; i++) {
    printf("Fib(%3d) %s.\n", i, str_add(fib[2], fib[1], fib[0]));
    strcpy(fib[0], fib[1]);
    strcpy(fib[1], fib[2]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Fib(  2) 1.
Fib(  3) 2.
Fib(  4) 3.
Fib(  5) 5.
Fib(  6) 8.
...
Fib(100) 3542248xxxxxxxxxx5075.  // Some xx left in for a bit of mystery.

Fib(1000) --> 43466...about 200 more digits...8875
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print some large Fibonacci numbers using only **char**, **int** and `<stdio.h>` in C.

There is some **headers** :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define B_SIZE 10000 // max number of digits
typedef int positive_number;

struct buffer {
    size_t index;
    char data[B_SIZE];
};
```

Also some **functions** :

```c
void init_buffer(struct buffer *buffer, positive_number n) {
    for (buffer->index = B_SIZE; n; buffer->data[--buffer->index] = (char) (n % 10), n /= 10);
}

void print_buffer(const struct buffer *buffer) {
    for (size_t i = buffer->index; i < B_SIZE; ++i) putchar('0' + buffer->data[i]);
}

void fly_add_buffer(struct buffer *buffer, const struct buffer *client) {
    positive_number a = 0;
    size_t i = (B_SIZE - 1);
    for (; i >= client->index; --i) {
        buffer->data[i] = (char) (buffer->data[i] + client->data[i] + a);
        buffer->data[i] = (char) (buffer->data[i] - (a = buffer->data[i] > 9) * 10);
    }
    for (; a; buffer->data[i] = (char) (buffer->data[i] + a), a = buffer->data[i] > 9, buffer->data[i] = (char) (buffer->data[i] - a * 10), --i);
    if (++i < buffer->index) buffer->index = i;
}
```

Example usage :

```c
int main() {
    struct buffer number_1, number_2, number_3;
    init_buffer(&number_1, 0);
    init_buffer(&number_2, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2500; ++i) {
        number_3 = number_1;
        fly_add_buffer(&number_1, &number_2);
        number_2 = number_3;
    }
    print_buffer(&number_1);
}

// print 131709051675194962952276308712 ... 935714056959634778700594751875
```

Best C type is still **char** ? The given code is printing `f(2500)`, a 523 digits number.

**Info** : `f(2e5)` has 41,798 digits, see also [Factorial(10000)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71866475/18765627) and [Fibonacci(1000000)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71888675/18765627).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the n-th fibonacci number is (approximately) `((1 + sqrt(5))/2)^n`.

This allows you to get the value for n that allows the result to fit in 32 /64 unsigned integers. For signed remember that you lose one bit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could want to try implementing BigInt in C++ or C.

Useful Material:

- [How to implement big int in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269268/how-to-implement-big-int-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

For this purporse you need implement BigInteger. There is no such build-in support in current c++. You can view few advises on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269268/how-to-implement-big-int-in-c)

Or you also can use some libs like [GMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library)

Also here is some implementation:

1. [E-maxx](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/big_integer) - on Russian language description.
2. Or find some open implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=biginteger&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Answer (score 0):

`Try to use a different format and printf`, use unsigned to get wider range of digits.

If you use `unsigned long long` you should get until `18 446 744 073 709 551 615` so until the 93th number for fibonacci serie  12200160415121876738 but after this one you will get incorrect result because the 94th number `19740274219868223167` is **too big** for unsigned long long.