# C++ long long issues

Tags: c++, long-long

I've been using signed long longs and have had weird issues with it - i.e. inconsistent behavior. I.e.

```
long long i;
printf("%d", i);
```

This tends to print values which have no relevance to the actual value of i (this also occured with cout).

It also has random behavior with `%`, i.e.

```
if(i % x == 0)
        //some code
```

This would sometimes run i.e. if `i = 15` and `x = 5` it just wouldn't return true and therefore the if statement would not run the code.

It would tend to return true on `x = 7` for some reason.

I believe that it may be a fault with the compiler which I believe was just the g++ compiler (it was at a competition).

Any ways to mitigate this or why it was doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `long long i; printf("%d", i);` This is **Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: Should I have added %lld?

Comment: @Cjen1 _"I believe that it may be a fault with the compiler ..."_ That's a very rare case, most of the time it's your code that has the bug.

Comment: Perhaps reading http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf might help

Comment: In C++ you should use `cout` instead and ignore the type specifier problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/6400180/995714 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2844/995714

Comment: With your mod problem, what happended when you assigned the result of 'i % x' to a temp var and printed it out?

Comment: I got the incorrect answer (that was with cout)

Comment: @Cjen1 _"I got the incorrect answer (that was with cout)"_ Can you provide a [MCVE] please?

Answer (score 0):

To print the various integer types using printf-style syntax requires horrible syntax - I suggest using the C++ type-safe iostreams instead.